# Archive Validation Error: Your Application Bundle must install to /Applications

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store-connect

For the release of my OSX - Application I changed the name from a working title to the final title. I changed the project name with file inspector.

The Project now contains several Periods (.) in its title.

Following files changed:
 - contents-xcworkspacedata
 - user.xcuserdatad
 - (Application name)-info.plist
 - project.pbxproj
 - (Application name).xcsheme

and now I get this error during archive validation:

**Archive Validation Error: Your Application Bundle must install to /Applications**

I reviewed my project target and the target directory is correct:
[image]

I also have a static-library as sub-project(target) in my workspace. But there the deployment is set to "Skip install"

How can I correct this problem?

**Update:**

I forgot to mention that I had to hardcode the *Bundle Identifier* to avoid a renaming.

The application directory is set with the variable **$(LOCAL_APPS_DIR)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the punctuation in the app-name solved the problem. 
It seems the validation process is using a regular expression like .*.app. And filenames with several "." cannot be matched.